# Huge variance for RandomForestRegressor models

Tags: python, random-forest, nvidia

The experiment is the following:

1. train a RFR with a 15k train rows
2. get predictions on 8k test rows, save predictions as **y_hat0**
3. ***remove 1 random row*** from the training set and retrain the RFR
4. save prediction for the newly trained model as **y_hat1**

Comparing y_hat0 and y_hat1 shows large discrepancies in model output:

- median diff: 1.8%
- 90th diff : 4.3%
- 99th diff: 6.7%

This are the results obtained with **n_estimators=350** and **min_sample_split=55**.
Going up to **n_estimators=2000** and **min_sample_split=200** leads to better results but at a huge computational cost (fitting time x 6):

- median diff: 0.5%
- 90th diff: 1.2%
- 99th diff: 1.9%

So I am wondering if just 1 row less out of 15k should have such a dramatic impact on model outputs? I thought RF were more robust than that to the slightest change in training data.

Any thoughts appreciated